# Quel tour est correct: « Il n’y en a plus qu'un disponible » ou « Il n’y en a plus qu'un de disponible »

Tags: constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

L’usage ou non de « de » dans cette construction semble flottant. Qu’en dirait le bon vieux Grevisse (référence en matière de bon français) sur ce sujet (Je n’ai pas accès au dictionnaire « Le bon usage ». Si les deux se disent, quelle serait la construction la plus littéraire (avec ou sans « de »).

Comment: Il pronom personnel ou il impersonnel? Il me semble, à moins que je ne me trompe, qu'il faille un "y" quelque part pour l'expression impersonnel: Il y a

Comment: En effet j’ai posé la question à la hâte! Merci

Comment: Les deux sont possibles mais le sens est différent.

Comment: @Lambie Je l'avais déjà indiqué dans ma réponse.

Comment: Mais il faut corriger la question. La question oú les deux tournures disent la même chose. Les deux disent: que un.

Comment: @Lambie La question ne portait pas sur ce point. Les deux tournures sont différentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sous le titre « Construction de l'attribut », dans « *Le bon usage* » (14ème édition) on trouve  à la § 244 des *Règles générales* la division "d)" qui traite de comment l'attribut du « sujet réel » (*il y a, il est, il reste, il se trouve*) est introduit.

> d)
> L'adjectif et surtout le participe passé qui accompagnent, comme
> attributs du « sujet réel », *il y a, il est, il reste, il se trouve*, peuvent être introduits par *de*, notamment quand le nom sujet réel est accompagné d'une indication de quantité (article indéfini, numéral, déterminant indéfini). Ce tour est fréquent dans la langue parlée ; il n'a rien d'incorrect, et se trouve d'ailleurs parfois dans l'écrit.
>
> ♦ Il y eut cent hommes DE tués.  (dans Littré, s, v. de, 7°)
> ♦ Il y eut encore quelques mots D'échangés.  (STENDHAL, Chartr., XIV)
> ♦ Il n'y aurait pas un couteau DE levé sur moi.  (MUSSET, Lorenz., III, 3)
> ♦ Il y avait eu six mille Barbares DE tués.  (FLAUB., Sal., IX)
> ♦ Il y eut [...] je ne sais combien de moutons DE tués.  (A. DAUDET, C. du lundi, Décoré du 15 août)
> ♦ Il faut qu'il y ait quelque  enfant DE malade.  (PROUST, Rech., 1.1, p. 55)
> ♦ Il y a eu des fautes DE commises.  (ib., t. III, p. 227)
> ♦ Il y a un pari D'engagé.  (ROMAINS, Copains, p. 8)
>
> On peut aussi considérer que le *de* accompagne un attribut du sujet (le nom, que le démonstratif ne fait qu'annoncer) dans *C'était déjà un bon pas DE
> fait*.  (HUGO, Misér., IV, XV, 1)
>
> Cette construction apparaît aussi
> — avec l'attribut du complément d'objet direct notamment des verbes *avoir, posséder, voir, rencontrer, connaître, remarquer, trouver, etc.*,
> — avec l'attribut des compléments de voici et voilà,
> — avec des attributs de phrases averbales
> ♦  Nous n'avons plus que la langue DE libre. (CHAT., Mém., III, II, IX, 11)
> ♦ Il a un cheval qui n'a que les pattes de devant DE mauvaises. (J. RENARD, Journal, 6 sept. 1899
> ♦ Voilà une classe DE passée.  (FROMENTIN, Domin., IV)
> ♦ Palforio. [...] Qu'est-ce ? / Un matelot. Un
> bateau D'échoué sur la côte.  (MUSSET, Prem. poés., Marrons du feu, I)
> ♦ Encore une journée DE perdue pour le travail !.  (MAURIAC, Feu sur la terre, p. 13  0)
>
> Dans les cas examinés ci-dessus, le *de* n'est pas obligatoire
> ♦ Il y eut cent hommes tués.  (dans Littré, s. v. avoir, Rem. 1)
> ♦  Il n'y a eu que trois élèves admis sur dix.   (Ac. 1932, s. v. admettre) [Ex. disparu en 2001.]
> ♦ Les Suisses eurent trois ou quatre soldats tués ou blessés.  (CHAT., Mém., III, II, XI, 5)
> ♦ Avez-vous encore une place libre dans la malle ?.  (VERNE, Drame en Livonie,
> IV)
> ♦ Aussitôt qu'il avait un jour libre.  (GIDE, Feuillets d'automne, Pl., p. 1093)
>
> Le de est très fréquent quand l'expression comporte le pronom *en*
> ♦ Sur cent habitants, il y en a deux DE riches.  (dans Littré, s. v. de, Rem. 5)
> ♦ Sur dix, il n'y en avait pas un DE bon.  (Ac. 1935, s. v. sur)
> ♦  C'est incroyable où est allé ce peloton. Je n'en ai qu'un DE jaune, et il faut qu'il s'envole.  (MUSSET, Il
> ne faut jurer de rien, II, 1)
> ♦  On en [= des ladies] voyait D'étalées dans des voitures.  (FLAUB., Mme Bov., I, 6)
> ♦ En voilà encore une [= une nuit] DE passée !. (SAND, Homme de neige, t. II, p. 250)
>
> Assez rarement avec un nom
> ♦  Des membres de cette assemblée, il y en a trois
> DE ministres.  (dans Martinon, pp. 192-193)
> Sans de
> ♦  Sur quatre femmes, il y en a toujours trois frisées.  (TAINE, Voy. en
> It., t. II, p. 188)
> ♦  Sur neuf prises, il m'en reste deux bonnes.  (COCTEAU, La
> belle et la bête, p. 90)
> Le de est obligatoire
> — 1) quand l'adjectif attribut précède son sujet et que le verbe est construit avec ne ... que ;
> — 2) quand l'adjectif se rapporte à *quelqu'un, quelque chose, personne, rien*, à *que* relatif, à *que* et *quoi* interrogatifs, à *ceci* et *cela*.
>
> ♦ Il n'y a D'universel que ce qui est suffisamment grossier pour l'être.  (VALÉRY,
> Mauvaises pensées et autres, Pl., p. 881)
> ♦ Il n'est sans doute DE purs que les solitaires.  (BOSCO, Mas Théotime, 1947, p. 338)
> ♦ Majorien. Cimber vous a battus. / L'homme. Nous n'avons DE battu que le fer de nos casques.  (HUGO, Lég., V, 8)
> ♦ Je ne sais DE reçu par elle que notre ami Thureau-Dangin [,..], et aussi
> Gaston Boissier.  (PROUST, Rech., t. II, p. 1056)
> Sur l'accord de l'adjectif, voir §§ 249, b, 1°, et 308, a, 5°.
> ♦ Il y a quelqu'un DE malade. — Un des traits que le paysage avait DE remarquable.  (ROMAINS, cit. Le Bidois, § 1831)
> ♦ Qu'a-t-il DE remarquable ? — Il y avait ceci D'étrange dans ces négociations que les concessions successives ne rapprochaient pas de l'état de paix.  (MAUROIS, Bernard Quesnay, p. 81)
> Cependant, avec un verbe comme trouver, le *de* sert à introduire l'épithète,
> tandis que l'attribut du complément d'objet se construit sans préposition
> ♦  Il a trouvé ceci DE remarquable. Il a trouvé ceci remarquable.

Cet usage appartient donc à la langue parlée, mais il se trouve aussi parfois dans la langue écrite.
Comme l'expression comporte le pronom « en » il est beaucoup plus fréquent d'utiliser « de », cependant la phrase sans « de » n'est pas incorrecte.

Comment: Réponse très détaillée LPH. Je t’en remercie!

Answer (score 1):

La formule largement la plus courante est :

> *Il n'en a plus qu'un de disponible.* (la personne n'en a plus qu'un)

ou

> *Il n'y en a plus qu'un de disponible.* (un seul est disponible à cet endroit)

mais à l'oral, ce sera souvent *plus qu'un d'disponible* qui peut faire croire que le *de* a disparu.

D'autre part, à l'écrit comme à l'oral l'élision est la règle: *qu'un*.

Remarque: On n'utilise pas *que 1* ou encore moins *qu'1* dans un texte :

> Les chiffres arabes appartiennent au langage mathématique.
> Lorsqu'il s'agit d'un texte ordinaire destiné à autrui, on ne les utilise que dans des cas particuliers, notamment pour indiquer les dates, les heures (sauf midi et minuit), les numéros de pages, d'immeubles, et aussi pour transcrire des nombres très complexes.
> LBU Ch. II, §115

Comment: J’ai écrit que un car la question m’est venu en lisant  « Il n’y en a plus que 1 de disponible »  alors que je faisais des achats sur Amazon.  Comme je l’ai dit plus haut, j’ai posé la question à hâte, je tâcherai à l’avenir d’attacher plus de soin et de prendre plus temps à la rédaction de mes questions.

Comment: À noter que ta réponse est de qualité, mais celle de LPH comprend plus de détails et renvoie de surcroît à l’ouvrage de référence sur laquelle je voulais que la réponse prenne appui.

Comment: Tu recherches un français normatif donc incompatible avec 1 en chiffres dans un texte. L'élision est obligatoire devant un et l'écrire en chiffres ne change rien. *Que un* est du français parlé très relâché, ce qui ne semble pas être ta tasse de thé... ;-)

Comment: Comme souvent on peut trouver quelques exceptions, *Un et demi est plus grand que un*.

Comment: En effet tu as raison pour ce qui est de 1 en chiffres, en revanche je n’ai fait que recopier à la hâte mot pour mot et chiffre pour chiffre ce que j’ai lu sur le site internet d’Amazon, indifféremment de la norme. Cela étant, la question portait sur l’emploi du déterminant « de » devant un adjectif, tu m’as fourni une réponse de qualité et je t’en remercie!

Comment: Les phrases construites automatiquement par des programmes, en plusieurs langues et à partir de modèles prédéfinis risquent plus que d'autres de ne pas être très académiques.